# Campo de text HTML/JS para data não funciona no Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Eu tenho o código abaixo como um input para a data , funciona bem em todos os navegadores excepto no Firefox. Provavelmente tem algo a ver com o `event.returnValue=false` ser ignorado pelo navegador, como corrijo isso?

```
        <html>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function Data(evento, objeto){
            var keypress=(window.event)?event.keyCode:evento.which;
            campo = eval (objeto);
            if (campo.value == '00/00/0000')
            {
                campo.value=""
            }

            caracteres = '0123456789';
            separacao1 = '/';
            conjunto1 = 2;
            conjunto2 = 5;          

            if ((caracteres.search(String.fromCharCode(keypress))!=-1) && campo.value.length < (10))
            {
                if (campo.value.length == conjunto1 )
                        campo.value = campo.value + separacao1;
                else if (campo.value.length == conjunto2)
                        campo.value = campo.value + separacao1;
            }
                else
                        event.returnValue = false;
         }  

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method=post action="">
        Data: <input type="text" name="txtdata" pattern="[0-9]" maxlength="10" size="10" onKeyPress="Data(event, this)">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Qual é a intenção com esse event.returnValue = false?

Comment: A intenção é que a input box não faça nada caso o if não seja verdadeiro, porém o firefox simplesmente insere a tecla digitada como entrada de texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta função realmente não é compatível com o Firefox.

Para esta ação, você pode usar o `event.preventDefault()` ou simplesmente retornar false para a function (`return false`).

Seu código alterado:

```
<html>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function Data(evento, objeto){
            var keypress=(window.event)?event.keyCode:evento.which;
            campo = eval (objeto);
            if (campo.value == '00/00/0000')
            {
                campo.value=""
            }

            caracteres = '0123456789';
            separacao1 = '/';
            conjunto1 = 2;
            conjunto2 = 5;          

            if ((caracteres.search(String.fromCharCode(keypress))!=-1) && campo.value.length < (10))
            {
                if (campo.value.length == conjunto1 )
                        campo.value = campo.value + separacao1;
                else if (campo.value.length == conjunto2)
                        campo.value = campo.value + separacao1;
            }
                else
                        evento.preventDefault();
         }  

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method=post action="">
        Data: <input type="text" name="txtdata" pattern="[0-9]" maxlength="10" size="10" onKeyPress="Data(event, this)">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Realizei a mudança para preventDefault() e posteriormente para return false, entretanto obtive o mesmo resultado, o código funciona normalmente em chrome, opera e safari, porém não no firefox.

Comment: Consegui fazer funcionar, como eu chamei event de evento na chamada de função só precisei alterar para `evento.preventDefault()`; Muito Obrigado Diego.

Comment: @JuscelinoDORNELES É verdade, eu coloquei event e deveria ser evento, legal que conseguiu corrigir, aproveitei e alterei a resposta. abs